# Carousel (multi image slider) in ExtJS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, carousel

Is there any way to design a carousel (slider having multiple images and sliding in horizontal direction) in ExtJS 4?

I want to implement something like this for my existing ExtJS 4 project:

[image]

You can see the above carousel by searching "Top dishes" on Google.

Can it be acheived by ExtJS 4 widgets or I have to use any external Javascript/CSS plugin or code?

Any working code, link or example will be highly helpful.

Comment: https://github.com/parham-fazel/extjs-carousel/blob/master/Ext.ux.Carousel.js

Comment: But it is not a muti image carousel

Comment: Did you know that stack overflow is made for help developers and not to give work to them? where is your try? where are errors to correct?

Comment: @Mr.Bruno I know that carousel is not a widget in ExtJs 4, but I wanted to know if someone has used carousel in ExtJs 4 ever, using existing widgets. Any blog or way to do that?

Comment: You should try it with a dataview, I think is the only way

Answer (score 0):

ExtJs 4 already has widgets that would help you creating such a slider.

You can use `DataView` along with a nice `itemTpl` and a `Store` containing the dishes ;)